# Angular resource $save has no push method

Tags: angularjs

in Angular i've got the following factory:

```
.factory('User', function($resource){
    return $resource(
        '/users',//URL
        {},//Params defaults
        {
            'save': {method: 'POST', isArray: true }
        }//Actions
    ) ;
})
```

And in my controller I try to save a new resource like so:

```
    $scope.newUser = new User() ;

    $scope.newUser.name = $scope.newUserForm.name ;
    $scope.newUser.email = $scope.newUserForm.email ;

    $scope.newUser.$save() ;
```

I get an array back from the server looking like that:

[
      {id: 12,
       username: "adfsdf",
       email: "sadfsf@sdf.com"
      }
   ]

But somehow I still get and error in the console:

TypeError: Object # has no method 'push'

Any idea where I'm missing something?

Thanks

Comment: It looks like the response from the server is an object, not an array - are you sure the response is `[ {id: 12, username: "adfsdf", email: "sadfsf@sdf.com" } ]`?

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me, that your User-Resource at the client is not an array and thats why it is missing the push-method.

```
'save': {method: 'POST', isArray: true }  //<---- You say it is an array.

$scope.newUser = new User() ; <-- create it

$scope.newUser.name = $scope.newUserForm.name ; <--- put data into it
$scope.newUser.email = $scope.newUserForm.email
```

Now user looks like:

```
{
  name:"somename",
  email:"some@email.com"
}
```

So it is no array. When your Server responds, angular trys to push the answer into that "array" but matter of fact, it is not an array.

So I would recommend to leave "isArray:true" out, because one User is not an Array. There is not a collection of Users.

I don't know, how angular responds to your server response, when it is presented array-style, just try it.